# Context manager inside a class instance

Tags: python

I would like to create a context manager class that's specific for an instance of another class. I can do it by calling a method that creates a class, but I'm not sure this is the best, nicest way:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 0
        self.Nest = self.create_context_manager()
    def inclev(self):
        self.level += 1
    def declev(self):
        self.level -= 1

    def create_context_manager(self):
        self2 = self
        class Nest(object):
            def __init__(self):
                pass
            def __enter__(self):
                self2.inclev()
            def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
                self2.declev()
        return Nest

# Manually increase/decrease level
my_instance = MyClass()
print(my_instance.level)
my_instance.inclev()
print(my_instance.level)
my_instance.inclev()
print(my_instance.level)
my_instance.declev()
print(my_instance.level)
my_instance.declev()
print(my_instance.level)

# Use instance-specific context manager
other_instance = MyClass()
print(other_instance.level)
with other_instance.Nest():
    print(other_instance.level)
    with other_instance.Nest():
        print(other_instance.level)
    print(other_instance.level)
print(other_instance.level)
```

Comment: It really helps people read your code if you use standard naming conventions. It also makes the syntax highlighting work. Look at pep8.

Comment: I've edited your code (non-functionally). Could you check I haven't changed anything relevant to the question?

Comment: @Holloway Sorry about that. Yes, the changes are OK.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why do you need a nested class? Just have the main object implement the context management protocol directly:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 0
    def inclev(self):
        self.level += 1
    def declev(self):
        self.level -= 1

    __enter__ = inclev  # For __enter__, just alias inclev, no need for wrapper
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.declev()
```

Then just use it with:

```
with other_instance:
    print(other_instance.level)
    with other_instance:
        print(other_instance.level)
    print(other_instance.level)
```

If you really need the context manager protocol as a constructed thing named `Nest`, you can still simplify a bit with builtins from `contextlib`:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 0
    def inclev(self):
        self.level += 1
    def declev(self):
        self.level -= 1

    @contextmanager
    def Nest(self):
        self.inclev()
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            self.declev()
```

Comment: I may need different context managers in the class. I could still implement several ones in a single way (by passing parameters), but I'd rather have the simplicity (from the usage point of view) of different names. I will consider this anyway.

Comment: @Jellby: I just finished the "same usage pattern as in the question but simplified code" example (I posted the "best" approach first, then edited to add alternate). That would cover your desired use case.

Comment: Thanks, I like the second way better.

Comment: While there might be a case that makes this seem natural, right now it's horrifying. Just as a matter of not pissing off the guy who will have to read this code in a year (especially if it's yourself!), having the object itself implement the nesting behavior without any kind of indicator is creepy.

Comment: @AustinHastings: Perhaps. Depends on whether the object is primarily concerned with level tracking or not. `threading.RLock` is basically the same design, it locks when it's not the owner, and increments/decrements the count until it hits 0 then unlocks, and you use it with just `with myrlock:`. Mixing many disparate behaviors in a single class is confusing no matter what; that's not really relevant to using (or not using) context managers.